# Vue handle null in nasted array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm from Ruby language so sorry for noob question. I've got this response from API:

```
[{:id=>"61b79d02a0f6af001374744e",
  :name=>"Waffle Crewneck",
  :code=>"FW22KS000",
  :result=>{"status"=>"Success", "message"=>"FW22KS000 - Synced"},
  :last_sync_at=>Wed, 18 May 2022 23:51:45.195079000 UTC +00:00},{:id=>"611ea9a7392ab50013cf4713", :name=>"2-Tone Hoodie", :code=>"SS22CH013", :result=>nil, :last_sync_at=>nil},]
```

Which I want to display inside of the table:

```
<tr v-for="product in fetchedProductSyncStatus" :key="product">

<td class="text-bold">
  {{ product.result.status }}
</td>
<td class="text-bold">
  {{ product.result.message }}
</td>
<td class="text-bold">
  {{ product.last_sync_at }}
</tr>
```

Because in second array element `product.result == nil` I've got an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')

Looking for something similar to Ruby's `product.result&.message`. How to avoid such error in Vue and display empty string instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the same thing in TypeScript, called optional chaining. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
{{ product.result?.message }}
```

Or the old-style `product.result && product.result.message`

Edit: Optional chaining in templates only works in Vue3

Comment: Interesting `{{ product.result?.message }}` crashed the app with an error `Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):` but the old-style works well.

Comment: Yeah sorry optional chaining in templates is only supported in vue3 (but works in script section)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more of a javascript rather than Vue issue... you can do something like this to check if `product.result` is available:

`{{product.result ? product.result.status : null}}` or

`{{ product.result && product.result.status }}`